# Converting Dos Command to Power Shell command

Tags: powershell, dos, starteam, psake

I am working with PowerShell 2.0 with Psake 1.4

Here is the dos command that is running that I want to convert to PowerShell.

```
"C:\Program Files\Borland\StarTeam 2005 R2\stcmd.exe" co -p "rubble.barney:dinno@HostName:4455/MySolution/WebApp" -is  -fp "D:\FooBar\MySolution\Source"
```

Notice that the path to stcmd has a space in it
 
Notice that there is a : between barney:dinno
Notice there area three quoted strings.

Here are my script properties and notes

$AppName     = "MySolution"
$StarExe     = "C:\Program Files\Borland\StarTeam 2005 R2\stcmd.exe"
$StarProject = "rubble.barney:dinno@HostName:4455/$AppName/WebApp"
$StarOutDir   = "D:\FooBar\$AppName\Source"
$StarCommand = """$StarExe"" co -p ""$StarProject"" -is -nologo -q -fp ""$StarOutDir"""

task default -depends GetSource

task Init {
"Working on $AppName"
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
}

task GetSource -depends Init {
'Get Soure From Star Team'
 ***correct to use invoke?  Should it be &,  or exec { }***
invoke-item $StarCommand
}

Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
& $starexe co -p $StarProject -is -nologo -q -fp $StarOutDir
```

I presume you're using powershell 2.0. Version 1.0 of powershell had way quirkier native command* argument parsing.

- native commands = exe, com, bat files etc.

-Oisin

Comment: That I tried 
& $StarExe co -p $StarProject -is -nologo -q -fp $StarOutDir

 and got:
Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '"C' does not exist.

Comment: bizarre. have you tested it with really simple arguments, like "& $prog" where $prog is, um, say "c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe" ?

Comment: It was a quotes issue with the path in the variable, doh!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
& $StarExe co -p $StarProject -is -nologo -q -fp $StarOutDir
```

Disclaimer: I haven't use psake but I'm not sure why you need so many double quotes around the variables.  FWIW the above command should work if executed in a PowerShell script.

Comment: You have to watch the PowerShell tag like a hawk to get an answer in edgewise these days.  :-)

Comment: I don't even get to answer almost anything here these days :-( – ah well, there's still the `batch` tag :-)

Comment: Heh, yeah that helps too.  :-)